# IOS UUID Change case

Tags: ios, uuid, uidevice

We already have sale app on app store.(This made by Objective-c)
But I'll upload new project for upgrade.(This made by swift4)

This case

```
"[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString]"
```

return 
"uuid-string-value"`  **will be changed?**

Comment: Its swift 4 version `UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString` does the same thing...

Comment: I saw uuid value sometimes changed...

Comment: Check this out https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What does "will be changed" mean?

Answer (score 2):

By [@Mahendra's link, developer.apple.com/document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor).

It said `uuid` will change in some conditions.

> If the value is nil, wait and get the value again later. This happens,
>   for example, after the device has been restarted but before the user
>   has unlocked the device. The value in this property remains the same
>   while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on
>   the iOS device.
>
> `The value changes` when the user deletes all of that
>   vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more
>   of them. The value can also change when installing test builds using
>   Xcode or when installing an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution.
>   Therefore, if your app stores the value of this property anywhere, you
>   should gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes.